# using CSS or javascript/jQuery, which method would I use to make my site's nav bar look more 3d-ish?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I see a lot of companies have the grey bar on top look a bit "round" instead of flat. I'm guessing it's more than just `background: grey` in css? how would i make it look like it pops out a little bit?

Comment: Shadows and gradients would be a start.

Comment: Could you link to an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use a CSS Gradients for modern browsers. You can generate the code at websites like this one: http://gradients.glrzad.com/

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,72,179) 38%, rgb(100,199,217) 78%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,72,179) 38%, rgb(100,199,217) 78%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,72,179) 38%, rgb(100,199,217) 78%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,72,179) 38%, rgb(100,199,217) 78%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(84,72,179) 38%, rgb(100,199,217) 78%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.38, rgb(84,72,179)),
    color-stop(0.78, rgb(100,199,217))
);
```

Also you can look at CSS Border radius code for rounded edges. This website will give you the code http://border-radius.com/

For older browsers, which don't support CSS Gradients, you would need to either look at background images, or something else.

**Update**

As **handsofaten** has pointed out, css3pie.com can be used to provide support for older browers when using modern css.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with css3 for sure, most people nowadays use modern enough browsers to make full use of css3 properties. box-shadows, text-shadows, transparency, borders and much more goodies
to build really stylish site with css3. 
Have a look at [www.css3.info](http://www.css3.info) for a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a combination of box-shadow and rounded borders (border radius). Adding a gradient is also a nice way to get a fresher look.